# Ordered sums: series, in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I need help with this analysis question.

Find all values of $x$ for which the the following series converges and determine the sum:
$\displaystyle x + \frac {x}{1 + x} + \frac{x}{(1 + x)^2} + \frac{x}{(1 + x)^3} + \frac{x}{(1+x)^4} + ....$

Comment: Of course people here want to help you, but this is the second question you make in 5 minutes. 
Did you tried before asking here?
If yes, would be a good idea to show what you did so far.

Answer (score 2):

Factoring $x + \frac {x}{1 + x} + \frac{x}{(1 + x)^2} + \frac{x}{(1 + x)^3} + \frac{x}{(1+x)^4} + ....$, we see that this is:

$x + \frac {x}{1 + x} + \frac{x}{(1 + x)^2} + \frac{x}{(1 + x)^3} + \frac{x}{(1+x)^4} + .... = x(1+\frac{1}{1+x} + \frac{1}{(1+x)^{2}} + \cdots)$

Now let $u = 1+x$.

Then the above some becomes:

$$(u-1)*\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{u})^{n}$$

For what values of $u$ is the geometric series convergent?